# Call existing Excel Macros with phpExcel

Tags: mysql, formatting, phpexcel

Once you export all of the data you need from MySQL into an Excel spreadsheet using PHP Excel, is it possible to call an existing Excel macro to apply formats to the data? If so could you provide an example, please?

Comment: Simple answer: No..... PHP is not particularly good at executing code written in other languages like VBA.... and while technically possibly, it was a lot of work, and a lot of system overhead for very little gain in enabling this in PHPExcel.

Comment: The question is, why do you need to use an Excel macro to format the data in the spreadsheet, when (if you're using PHPExcel to generate your spreadsheet) you can set all the formatting using PHPExcel before saving the file

Comment: The reason I asked is because currently I have VBA written to format the data exactly as I'd like, and using what's already written utilizes pivots tables and whatnot, and I'd rather use what's already written versus writing a bunch of uneccessary phpexcel code.

Comment: Then I fear you're stuck with using COM